# What options are there for displaying a map with a web app on the iphone?

Tags: iphone

I would like to include a map on a web site optimised to be displayed on an iphone. What options do I have for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Google Maps Api

[Google Maps API Family](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)

You may also be interested to have a look at this:

[iphone-google-maps-component](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-google-maps-component/)

Answer (score 1):

**If the website is accessed from a custom native iPhone app, you can use the [MapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) from the [MapKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) framework**, which provides an interface for embedding maps directly into iPhone windows and views. The MapKit framework uses Google services to provide map data.